# Split dataframe on sum column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [1, 2, 3, 6], 'Bar': ['hello', 'world', 'spam', 'eggs']})
>>> df
     Bar  Foo
0  hello    1
1  world    2
2   spam    3
3   eggs    6
```

How can I split this DataFrame so that each split portion has (roughly) the same sum of `Foo`? That is, if I want to split them into two, I'd like:

```
     Bar  Foo
0  hello    1
1  world    2
2   spam    3
```

and

```
     Bar  Foo
0   eggs    6
```

Since in both cases, `Foo` sums to 6.

I know that there's NumPy's [`array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html), i.e. `pd.np.array_split(df, 2)`, but this splits the DataFrame into portions with equal rows. How can I do the same, but with equal sum for a particular column?

Answer (score 3):

Improving upon the solution by @congusbongus

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [1, 2, 3, 6], 'Bar': ['hello', 'world', 'spam', 'eggs']})
>>> df['Foo_cumsum'] = df.Foo.cumsum()
>>> import math
>>> no_buckets = 4
>>> bucket_size = df.Foo_cumsum.max() / no_buckets
>>> df['bucket'] = (df.Foo_cumsum / bucket_size).apply(math.ceil)
>>> df
     Bar  Foo  Foo_cumsum  bucket
0  hello    1           1       1
1  world    2           3       1
2   spam    3           6       2
```

Change the number of buckets needed accordingly in the variable `no_buckets`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and then filter on that column. Example:

```
>>> df['Foo_cumsum'] = df.Foo.cumsum()
>>> df
     Bar  Foo  Foo_cumsum
0  hello    1           1
1  world    2           3
2   spam    3           6
3   eggs    6          12

>>> df[(df.Foo_cumsum > 0) & (df.Foo_cumsum <= 6)]
     Bar  Foo  Foo_cumsum
0  hello    1           1
1  world    2           3
2   spam    3           6
>>> df[(df.Foo_cumsum > 6) & (df.Foo_cumsum <= 12)]
    Bar  Foo  Foo_cumsum
3  eggs    6          12
```

Make sure you check for boundary cases like if the filter results in an empty DataFrame.